# Session / Log tables keys design question

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I have almost always heard people say not to use FKs with user session and any log tables as those are usually High write tables and once written data almost always tays forever without any updates or deletes.

But the question is I have colunms like these:
User_id (link a session or activity log to the user)
activity_id (linking the log activity table to the system activity lookup table)
session_id (linking the user log table with the parent session)
... and there are 4-5 more colunms.

So if I dont use FKs then how will i "relate" these colunms? Can i join tables and get the user info without FKs? Can i write correct data without FKs? Any performance impact or do people just talk and say this is a no no?

---

Another question I have is if i dont use FKs can i still connect my data with lookup tables?

Answer (score 1):

In fact, you can build the whole database without real FKs in mysql. If you're using MyISAM as a storage engine, the FKs aren't real anyway.
You can nevertheless do all the joins you like, as long as the join keys match.

Performance impact depends on how much data you stuff into a referenced table. It takes extra time if you have a FK in a table and insert data into it, or update a FK value. Upon insertion or modification, the FK needs to be looked up in the referenced table to ensure the reference integrity.

On highly used tables which don't really need reference integrity, I'd just stick with loose columns instead of FKs.

AFAIK InnoDB is currently the only one supporting real foreign keys (unless MySQL 5.5 got new or updated storage engines which support them as well). Storage engines like MyISAM do support the syntax, but don't actually validate the referential integrity.

Comment: I have InnoDB for all tables. The website is a social network so data is important. Well a log table in a social network (where we track every movement of a user - so you can imagine atleast 150-200 rows being added with tracking details per user, per login. So table size will grow. As for the parent tables which it is referencing to - user table will grow as new users join. The activity tables are mostly read only and rarely ever updated unless a new activity is added.

Answer (score 0):

FK's can be detrimental in "history log" tables. This kind of table wants to preserve the exact state of what happened at a point in time.

The problem with FK's is they don't store the value, just a pointer to the value. If the value changes, then the history is lost. You DO NOT WANT updates to cascade into your history log. It's OK to have a "fake Foreign key" that you can join on, but you also want to intensionally de-normalize relevant fields to preserve the history.

Comment: I should not have said "pointer". I am assuming a foreign key on a surrogate value. If you join on the surrogate key to get the latest values you are defeating the purpose of the log. A log is not about the latest values. It's about the values at that moment in time.